# Bridge Hosted Network with another network

Tags: windows-8, ad-hoc-network, wireless-bridge, virtual-wifi

I create a hostednetwork in windows 8-1.

after that i select the new virtual wifi and ethernet but there is no option to making bridge.

I have this problem because of the windows 8.1 did not support ad hoc network:(

I create a hostednetwork with the below command

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=sam key=qwert12345 keyusage=persistent
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"bridging is prohibited between the AP adapter and any other adapters in the system"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx