# Bridging two wireless adapters in Windows, receiving signal in one and sharing the internet (starting hotspot) through the other one

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-access-point, internet-sharing

I have Windows 10 Home edition, that came built in with my [Acer E5-573G-56RG](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.MVGAA.002). The problem is that I cannot start hotspot through the `netsh` command. The Home edition users aren't allowed to do that. (I came to this conclusion because I tried installing Windows 10 Pro edition and I was able to start hotspot in it).

I desperately need to share the wireless signal that I receive in my University, because only laptops' MAC addresses are registered by them and many times we require access to internet through our mobile phones (mine- Android 5.1.1).

I am seeing if I can bypass the restriction by bridging both the wireless adapters, receive the internet through the built-in one and share the internet through the other. How do I do this?
`netsh wlan show drivers` states **Hosted network supported** as **NO** for the built in adapter (in Home edition alone) and **YES** for the USB dongle. How do I modify the command to make the hotspot start from my dongle instead of it saying that it cannot start (from the built-in) one?

Or, preferably, is there a way to remove the restriction and bring Microsoft Virtual Hosted Network adapter in device manager? (Currently it is not seen, even with the **Show hidden devices** option enabled) (In Windows 10 Home edition).

Also Windows 10 doesn't support AdHoc type hotspot.

Comment: Bridging with virtual adapters are explicitly prohibited, see https://superuser.com/questions/682199/bridge-hosted-network-with-another-network

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my English but I will try my best to explain it.
it is possible to do it. All you need to do is remove the one adapter you going to connect to the internet and plug the 2nd adapter that supports to sharing or (hosted network supported : yes you can check this one on cmd by typing - Netsh WLAN show drivers). Then
open cmd and type "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=(Name) key=(8CharacterKey)" - Replace “Name” with the name you’d like to use for your custom network, and “8CharacterKey” with a password that’s you want but it must be 8 characterkey example 87654321 the you get the message

- The hosted network mode has been set to allow.
- The SSID of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
- The user key passphrase of the hosted network has been successfully changed.

after that to start the hosted type this "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" then you get this as a resalt 
* The hosted network started.
then all you have to do is go to network connections in control panel or simply copy this to and address bar " Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections " without the quotation mark.
then plug your 2nd adapter - connect to the wifi that you want - go to
network connections r

Comment: It's quiet long since I put up this question. Thank you for taking your time to write the answer. The issue has been solved with Windows updates as there is a built-in option now to use hotspot in Windows 10. Moreover I have switched to Ubuntu these days for other requirements and this problem has again started plaguing me as there is no way to share **wireless** internet in Ubuntu. Thank you once again!